# How to remove prettier plugin from ESLint in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

I've been using prettier plugin for ESLint for a while and now I've got project with different `.eslintrc.js`. My config use to be like:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  extends: [
    'airbnb',
    'prettier',
    'prettier/react',
  ],
  ...
  plugins: [
    'react',
    'prettier',
  ],
  rules: {
    'prettier/prettier': [
      'error',
      {
        'trailingComma': 'es5',
        'singleQuote': true,
        'printWidth': 120,
      }
    ],
    'react/jsx-filename-extension': [1, { 'extensions': ['.js', '.jsx'] }],
  },
  ...
};
```

I got rid of all of those rules & plugins & extensions, however, I still get this error:

> Failed to load plugin prettier: Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-prettier'
>   Happened while validating /.../file.js
>   This can happen for a couple of reasons:
>   1. The plugin name is spelled incorrectly in an ESLint configuration file (e.g. .eslintrc).
>   2. If ESLint is installed globally, then make sure 'eslint-plugin-prettier' is installed globally as well.
>   3. If ESLint is installed locally, then 'eslint-plugin-prettier' isn't installed correctly.

I don't really want to use it no more, but this error doesn't allow me to use ESLint at all. Could this be because plugin is installed globally as well? How do I get rid of this plugin?

### What I tried so far:

- deleting repo and cloning it from github with correct ESLint file.
- configuring ESLint file from template with `eslint --init`
- replacing file with absolutely random and ridiculous setting from web

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turned out that I had `.eslintrc.js` configuration in the upper folder which had a priority to load. Removing this file and keeping an existing one in project fixed my problem.