# Disabling prettier in ESLint in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

When I try to use the Microsoft ESLint extension in VSCode it complains about pretty much every line in my JS file being incompatible with Prettier. I thought Prettier was a separate extension and I don't have that extension installed as you can see:

[image]

I came across [How to remove prettier plugin from ESLint in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57594497/how-to-remove-prettier-plugin-from-eslint-in-vs-code) and [How to disable prettier in VSCode for a specific project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69478157/how-to-disable-prettier-in-vscode-for-a-specific-project) but neither one seemed to apply in my situation.  Is there a way I can disable the prettier aspect of ESLint in VSCode?

My C:\Users\myuserid\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json file looks like:

```
{
    "editor.accessibilitySupport": "off",
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "eslint.rules.customizations": [
    
    ]
}
```

My C:\Users\myuserid\source\react-native\TargetSum.vscode\settings.json

```
{
    "eslint.rules.customizations": [
    
    ]
}
```

Comment: What are the available extension settings?

Comment: I added my settings files, I don't see anything related to prettier.